# What should PhD students do if they submit a paper to two journals and a reviewer notices concurrent submission?

Tags: journals, editors, research-misconduct

I am in a desperate situation. I made a mistake and committed academic misconduct.

I have submitted my article to two journals in parallel, let's say in j1 and j2. Once I received acceptance from journal j1 I wrote a withdraw email to j2.

However, after the article came online it was found by the reviewer of j2 that the withdrawal article was actually a parallel submission.

I am 3rd year PhD student and my professor was unaware of this act. How can I handle this situation?

Should I write an apology email to j2? If j2 accept the apology, will j1 keep the article or still it will be retracted?

What is the best way to come out of the situation?

*I am reviewer of both journals as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58331/discussion-on-question-by-kumar-what-should-phd-students-do-if-they-submit-a-pap).

Answer (score 126):

If you are a seasoned reviewer you should know the rules, so falling back on being an inexperienced graduate student probably won't hold water. So clearly this was less a 'mistake' and more of a 'gamble'.  You should pull the article from both venues and state -unequivocally- that your advisor had no knowledge.

You didn't mention if your advisor was a co-author on the submission, but if he/she was, the infraction is even worse, because not only have you submitted without consent, you risked damaging their reputation with the journals as well.

The best path forward is to own your mistake wholly and apologize. On the positive side, it's not like you committed the mortal sin of fabricating data or plagiarizing - you violated a rule (and likely the terms and conditions of the journal). Probably not grounds for dismissal but you might be on a leash for a while.

Don't do it again!  The rule is in place for several reasons, not the least of which is respecting reviewers' time and effort (reviewers' time is precious and usually pro-bono. We can't have every journal reviewing the same work).

Comment: This! The scenario does indeed sound like a gamble and the remorse seems to be based on being caught out.

Comment: The odd thing is that it was never a very good gamble. j1 and j2 have enough subject overlap to share reviewers and receive similar papers. The paper is in their overlap area. The probability that nobody involved in reviewing it for j2 would also read it in j1 must be close to zero.

Comment: I think your recommendation is far too severe; don't you think that the matter could be settled amicably without a retraction?

Comment: "You should pull the article from both venues and state -unequivocally- that your advisor had no knowledge." @Kumar I just want to jump in here to say that I don't think that this warrants withdrawal of an accepted paper. Just apologise to the j2 reviewer, and don't do it again. If he pursues it further you have a problem, but he may not You don't say exactly what the reviewer said/did. Ahd who did he communicate with regarding this?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I wouldn't go so far as to retract from both journals, but I do think both journals deserve an apology and the opportunity to decide for themselves if they are going to reject the paper. Only apologizing to j2 will get you in very hot water once j1 gets wind of it.

Comment: Gamble? Submiting to a journal is always a gamble. Breaking the rules just means disrespecting the disastrous and aged system of academic journals.

Comment: @innisfree Retraction might not be *absolutely* required, but telling both journals *definitely* is - you likely violated their submission rules. Most reputable journals will be *very* miffed at you for simultaneous submission and may even pull the paper post-acceptance because of it. You messed up your reputation, and if you don't want to damage it further, you need to be honestly contrite about it. This involves honestly apologizing to all parties about the error, and offering to pull the paper (i.e. removing any benefit from your deceit) is part of that.

Comment: @Džuris And the people working for them for free that you rely on to get published.

Comment: This is a faux pas, but retracting the article is unnecessary and wrong from a scientific standpoint. If the article were retracted it would suggest that something was wrong with the research, not that the author broke some arbitrary rules about not submitting your articles to competing journals. Yes we all understand why they are there, but the research literature shouldn't suffer as a consequence.

Comment: Can the published article really be pulled at this stage? It's gone online already, people have read it... you can't remove it from the community's mind. Not to mention the fact that the PDF has been cached in a dozen places.

Comment: I am not a PHD student. Why exactly is this bad?

Comment: @terdon Gow is it not disrespectful to the reviewers? If I have spent many hours reviewing a paper and then when I am about done notice that paper published in another journal, that was a complete waste of my time. And this is a very likely outcome of double submission.

Answer (score 47):

Your best course is to write your professor, both journals, explain your reason sincerely, and let them handle the situation as they see fit.

Everyone make mistakes, and sometimes they are bad mistakes. In my opinion, trying to hide these mistakes or covering up would cost you more than the mistake itself in terms of academic reputation.

Comment: I would not advise writing at once to both the advisor and both journals. I'd go talk to my advisor - and my coauthors - first, immediately and face-to-face if possible; and this will definitely affect how I write the letter to the journal publishers.

Comment: The action can be altered, but main idea is to keep all the parties up-to-date.

Answer (score 34):

**TL;DR: Come clean with your advisor and coauthors first and hope that they help you.**

Concurrent submission is a big no-no, because it means you are wasting the time of the reviewers and editors by creating twice as much work as is necessary and you are effectively queue-jumping by doubling your chances of acceptance, which is unfair to other authors. Unless you have a good excuse, people will be very unhappy about this.

You will need to talk to your advisor and coauthors before taking further action. They will find out sooner or later and it is best if they hear it from you first. You must explain what you did, why you did it, that it was a terrible mistake, and that you sincerely regret it. Hopefully they will decide to help you resolve the situation.

Your advisor and coauthors will need to help you apologize to the journals.

Everyone makes mistakes. The important thing is that you must rectify them as soon as possible. If you appropriately apologize, then hopefully it can be forgiven and you can move on having learned an important lesson.

Concurrent submission is nowhere near as serious as, say, falsifying data. I hope that you are able to learn a lesson from this and that your reputation can be recovered. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for letting your coauthors know first. As a coauthor, I'd want to know what happened and I'd want to proofread your apologies to the journals, because it'd be my reputation on the line as well.

Answer (score 10):

I can't speak for how these journals will react,  but i can say that as a conference program chair the course of action was to reject from both venues.  My expectation would be for j2 to contact j1 and for j1 to rescind the acceptance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if j2 somehow accept the apology, bearing in mind I served j2 as a reviewer and reviewed 10s of articles. Still j1 will cancel the acceptance of article?

Comment: I don't think serving as reviewer has any bearing.

Comment: As for the apology... that's up to them,  and how seriously they treat the infraction will dictate what they do about it.

Comment: The question is: if you are that experienced as a reviewer - what was the reason for making the mistake? State that reason and apologise, perhaps they will give you the benefit of the doubt. However, I really do not hope your reason was "hedging", because that would be really not a good one to have.

Comment: If the answer was something other than hedging, I'd expect that to have come out in the question.  My money is on hedging, and I agree, OP should have known better, and most submission systems explicitly ask this. If they did here, for either j1 or j2, it is inexcusable.

Comment: @FredDouglis: The article was already published; what would a rescension (sp?) mean, other than an official loss of credit? The file's floating on-line, too, and I bet the printed copies have gone out. Nobody's going to go rip the pages out of those...

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how Kumar posed the question and @einpoklum is making statements about how it is already published.  Anyway, yeah, if it has already been formally published, it is much less likely that j1 will rescind it, but I really don't know all the details about how such ethical lapses are handled.  If they wanted to, they could probably purge their online presence of the article, though printed copies would survive.  But I imagine it's considered archival and immutable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have already got proper answers; however, the outcome of your apology depends on several factors.
1- if both journals belongs to same publisher I will expect a warning letter and maybe no further action will be taken. 
2- If journals belongs to different publisher than you are in tricky situation. First you need to apologise to j2 and inform your apology to j1. If j2 rejects your apology I will expect strong action from j1; at least retraction of article and possible ban. However, if j2 shows flexibility and just issue a warning than there is a high possibility that j1 will endorse the warning issued by j2 and matter will solved.
My recommendation to is don't hide or don't try to play smart. Apologise and you should mention about your services to journal. Might be Editor will show little flexible behaviour based on your voulenteer work.
Finally, never repeat such mistake.

Comment: I actually have the opposite reaction.  If they are the same publisher, I would think they are more likely to be bothered by the overlap, and more likely for the two EICs to communicate, meaning that it is IMHO more likely that j2 is peeved and gets j1 to rescind.  If they are independent, j2 has no sway with j1.

Comment: @FredDouglis If two publishers are involved, copyright issues might play a role. I'd expect publishers to take a dim view of misconduct that could potentially cause legal problems for them.

Comment: If they viewed it all along as simultaneous bites with the intention to withdraw one, they wouldn't think copyright would ever come into it. Only a waste of time and breach of ethics.  That being said, I have met Ph.D.s who have never been informed these rules apply. That's why it matters whether either submission system explicitly reminded the authors of this, as so many now do. If so, the apology rings hollow.

Comment: Downvoted; whether the journals have the same publisher or not has no bearing whatsoever on the issue.  Parallel submission isn't frowned on because it creates legal issues for the pulbisher(s); it's an issue of _professional ethics_.

Comment: JeffE two different publishers adds difficulty to deal with two different set of rules. why its hard to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Like it was stated in the other answers, your co-authors should be aware of the current state of this situation and the fact of parallel submission itself.

In terms of informing journals j1 and j2, as I see it: you may write a brief message to j1 (editor?) just informing that the (accepted) article has been also submitted to j2 due to *your* neglect but it is withdrawn from there, and write an apology letter to j2 (it would be good if you specifically indicate that it happened due to your mistake, neglect, etc.). By writing to j2 (reviewer) you 'pass a ball' to j2. So, then it is up to j2 whether to accept your apologies, escalate it to the next level (e.g. by contacting j1 and asking them to withdraw your manuscript) or do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You came here to ask an advice on how to handle this issue. But actually, you have no option.
Let your supervisor know, and he/she will tell you what you should do and how to handle it. 
For me, your university has a bigger responsibility than you. Your university should educate you regarding the scientific community before it allows you to submit a paper in a scientific journal, and not by giving you just a booklet with some info of Do and Dont. However, I am not removing your responsibility. Your supervisor and both journals are the real victims of all this situation.

Answer (score -11):

It might not help you much right now...

But a more tactical approach is to send two versions, differing by as much as you are comfortable in explaining the differences if this happens. Obvious obligatory differences:

1. different **titles**
2. different **focus on results**
3. **explaining** your method differently, example: many fields today are a mixture so researchers have literally each toe in a different field. Each field have their own journals and expect you to write things which are readable by their audience.
4. different **comparisons** to previous work done by others.

Voila and you have almost a whole new paper. Yes some extra work required, but not nearly as much and probably not nearly as stressful work as risking being pointed out as a cheater.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62562/discussion-on-answer-by-mathreadler-what-should-phd-students-do-if-they-submit-a).

Answer (score -29):

I tend to disagree with everyone here. One fellow noticed you submitted in parallel. So? That's not a problem yet.

Were you allowed to do that? Probably not. Should you have done it? Absoulutely.

Currently journals gamble with us. They take your article, hold it up for months and reject it in the end. Why shouldn't we do the same?

You can apply dor several jobs or schools at once just as schools and employers can consider a lot of options at once. The same should be true and acceptable for journals. The fact that it currently isn't is not your fault but the fault of journals displaying their power.

Comment: Couldn't disagree more. If you don't like the system - fine, don't use it. Or work to reform it. But abusing the system will make the situation worse, not better.

Comment: Additionally, it is terrible advice to give: people following it will be hurt badly. Don't confuse your dislike of the current rules with the proper way to handle them.

Comment: Once a paper is submitted, no action on the part of the author is required for the paper to be published. The reason why concurrent submissions are forbidden is to prevent double publishing, which is auto-plagiarizing.

Comment: "Were you allowed to do that? Probably not. Should you have done it? Absoulutely." Ah yes, the classic way to get respect and help your career in every field.  If there are rules about something, generally there is a reason.  Breaking those rules is an invitation for punishment.  Regardless of if you agree with those rules, this is not good advice.  It doesn't address the potential repercussions of choosing to ignore rules and regulations.  If you want to publish in other peoples journals, it's best advised to follow their rules.

Comment: To some extent I do agree with you there are flaws in the current peer review system. One of my article went got rejected after 14 months and that after minor revision. But you should follow the established norms and strive for change. I will like to hear from you what alternate practical solution and system will you suggest and how can you implement.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was not "Was I allowed to do that?" or "Should I have done that?", but "What should I do now?". I assume that your implied answer is "You should take no immediate action, keep making multiple submissions, and ignore any negative consequences of doing this.", but it would be helpful if you could make that explicit.

Comment: @MBK the alternatives are already there. Some have even become eligible for the Millenium prize while ignoring the journals.

Comment: It sounds like you have never been on the reviewer/editor side of the publishing process. It's a lot of work and authors should respect that by not spamming journals with concurrent submissions.

Comment: "Currently journals gamble with us. They take your article, hold it up for months and reject it in the end. Why shouldn't we do the same?" There certainly are inefficiencies, but usually "hold it up for many months" means that someone is slogging through your paper and verifying every line of it for months, taking time away from teaching and research, pro bono. It's not like your paper stays in a cupboard for six months and then you magically get a decision.

Comment: I wonder if there is some sort of academic version of Godwin's law where inevitably someone will involve Perelman as an example.

Comment: @Džuris How is ignoring the journals and trying to use them while lying to them and breaking their rules the same thing?

Comment: @Dzuris - how motivated would you be to provide a thoughtful review if you thought 30 other people were simultaneously reviewing the paper, and the author has hedged his/her bets with enough journals that even if you recommended reject, the author will probably get it in elsewhere?  It dilutes your contribution to the process.

Comment: I like your advice, in the real world, I hope that the authors have more rights.

Comment: As many problems as there are with the way academic publishing works, this isn't helping anything.  The process takes as long as it does because reviewing papers takes time and there are a lot of them.  If people submitted everything multiple times, that'd just slow the process down even more while making extra work for the unpaid volunteers (i.e. us).

Comment: I partially agree with the point you're making - but not with your concrete advice. You're bringing up an issue which merits at least serious discussion. The thing is, OP's situation is not a good context to hold that discussion.

Comment: @HEITZ: You're presenting an extreme. What about if some submissions you check had a note saying "I have submitted this paper on Foo Bars both to the Journal of Foo Research and to Bar Studies Quarterly". Would that really bother you?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, it would. I wouldn't review that manuscript then. My time is limited and I can't support authors that double the number of necessary reviews. I have to refuse review requests due to my work load even without concurrent submissions.

Comment: @Roland I see the problem in the fact that reviewers aren't respected (paid appropriately) either.