Am I allowed to submit a paper to a journal while it is under review at another?
Can you help answer these questions for me: SSRN (https://www.ssrn.com/index.cfm/en/) that is purchased by Elsevier claims of faster peer reviews with authors being notified within 3 days. In the research world, if I have a paper that is currently under publication review, am I allowed to submit that to SSRN as well before it is accepted?

also related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88871/what-should-phd-students-do-if-they-submit-a-paper-to-two-journals-and-a-reviewe

also related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/132594/can-i-submit-a-paper-to-two-or-more-journals-at-the-same-time

You cannot in general submit papers in parallel at all. The only exception is that law does a form of parallel submission. However, this rule also doesn't apply to SSRN because SSRN is not doing peer review. SSRN is a preprint server. Papers put on their are approved for the server or not, but they are not subject to peer review.

The one word answer is "No". If it were accepted by both journals, whoever would have the right to publish it, the one who accepts it first? What would the correct citation be?
